# Does ArcGIS for Server support Windows OS In Place upgrades?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, windows

I have ArcGIS for Server running on Windows Server 2008. The IT department wants to upgrade the server to Windows Server 2012. Does ESRI officially support this migration path? I know it was possible before but with the prevalence of VMs nowadays I'm not sure it's still supported. I can't find anything official on their website.

Comment: The question really might be whether *Microsoft* supports registry transfer.  Given the frequency of registry corruption that I've seen, you might be best off applying a new OS, patching it, installing AGS, then restoring your frequent Server configuration backup (with a defrag after each step). In the end Esri is the only reliable source for this answer; Tech Support is the place to ask.

Comment: I talked to ESRI technical support. As @Vince says the answer is more of a Microsoft question. Technical support says it is possible but not something they officially support. There are no instructions. The only advice they offerered was to stop the services before the upgrade and reinstall the web adapter afterwards.